# HOMEWORK: Need assistance inputing Mesh Analysis complex equations into TI89

Tags: homework, mesh-analysis, calculator

I am having calculator difficulties in regards to inputting my mesh equations into my TI-89. The answer I am receiving is not the answer that was presented in the solution provided by my TA. I also double checked that my mode was in degrees.

I uploaded the original solution and problem. The second link is to an image of my matrix.

[image]

---

Edit: Working link to my matrix: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xcbx.jpg

[image]

Comment: You need to show your calculation so that folk don't waste time going over stuff you know how to do.

Comment: Thats why I included a photo of my matrix setup. I setup the matrix and then put all of my data into the ti-89.

Comment: Have you searched the web?  There seems to be many videos and how-to pages on exactly this topic.  [Here is](http://spot.pcc.edu/~rbeng/ti89_92simult.html) a good one.  [This page](https://www.msubillings.edu/asc/resources/math/calculators/PDF-89/C89-SolveAndCsolve.pdf) covers cSolve which accomodates complex values.  The TI-89 [manual](https://education.ti.com/en/guidebook/details/en/2110B5BC591D44E1AF4C28F00A6614B6/8992p) covers it as well of course.

Comment: I found a video on youtube on how to input the numbers into a matrix and solve it as well as how to utilize the csolve function. I kept getting the wrong answer but I followed both instructions to the letter.

Comment: Your equations look right to me.  My eyes are old and I’m looking at it on a mobile. I will double check later when home.  You may wanna clear out those j terms in denominator (in case the fractions are contributing to an entry error) and use radians instead of degrees as a test.  I use the good old TI-85 so not sure about the pitfalls of the 89.

Comment: I worked it out myself on a scratch sheet of paper and I get the exact same answers as you do.  I used [this nice complex simultaneous solver](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1329101813).

Comment: @relayman357 would you be able to send me a picture of your work prior to inputing the data to that solver. The picture that is shown is the answer key to the problem. My matrix attempt is the image where you have to click the "imgur" link. Thanks!

Comment: My bad, when I said I got the same answers as yours, I meant I got the same answers as you show on that image. Not on your Imgur link.

Comment: @relayman357 Thank you very much for such a detailed response. I see exactly where I went wrong. I appreciate you taking the time to help me. I will most certainly use the MathJax tool for future references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare each of your loop equations to what I show below.

$$\text{Bottom left loop: }\text{ }-(-6j) + (i_1-i_3)(-\frac{2}{3}j) +  (i_1-i_2)=0 $$
$$\text{Upper left loop: }\text{ }5i_1+(i_3-i_4)(4j)+(i_3-i_1)(-\frac{2}{3}j)=0 $$
$$\text{Upper right loop: }\text{ }(i_4-i_2)(-\frac{1}{2}j)+(i_4-i_3)(4j)=0 $$
$$\text{Bottom right loop: }\text{ }9+(i_2-i_1)+(i_2-i_4)(-\frac{1}{2}j)=0 $$

Now, collecting terms and writing in matrix form,
$$Ax=b$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}(1-\frac{2}{3}j)&-1&\frac{2}{3}j&0\\(5+\frac{2}{3}j)&0&3\frac{1}{3}j&-4j\\0&\frac{1}{2}j&-4j&3\frac{1}{2}j\\-1&(1-\frac{1}{2}j)&0&\frac{1}{2}j\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}i_1\\i_2\\i_3\\i_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-6j\\0\\0\\-9\\\end{bmatrix}$$

Then solve however you want (e.g. in your TI-89).  I used [this nice](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1329101813) online complex capable simultaneous equation solver.  The results are,

$$\begin{bmatrix}i_1\\i_2\\i_3\\i_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-1.8-1.2j\\-7-0.033j\\-9.05+6.608j\\-9.34+7.556j\end{bmatrix}\text{amps}$$

And, thanks to that handy 1Ω resistor we can easily find Vx,

$$V_x=(i_1-i_2)(1Ω)=5.33\angle-12.65⁰\text{ V}$$

The above is a [phasor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor) which we can convert to,

$$V_x(t)=5.33 cos(2000t-12.65⁰)\text{ V}$$

p.s.  I recommend you take the time to enter your work in [MathJax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax#:%7E:text=MathJax%20can%20display%20mathematical%20notation,used%20to%20describe%20mathematical%20notation.) for 2 reasons.  It is much easier for people to read (vs. a camera snap) and it gives you a chance to slow down and check your work. This [neat tool](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) lets you draw symbols and it tells you the corresponding Latex code.